# How should I securely type a password in front of a lot of people?

Tags: authentication

I am a manager in an office where the company does not provide a company email, so I use my personal email.

Often, I will receive jobs lists by email from my general manager.

How should I log in to my email in front of my co-workers so that they don't see my password?

My email service uses end to end encryption, which means that it does not store or reset my password.

I also cannot move the screen so my co-workers cannot see it.

Comment: Create a new email just for work.

Comment: How does "end to end encryption" imply "can't reset password"?

Comment: That's the reason why password prompts usually show the same placeholder character for each character entered. Why isn't that sufficient in your case?

Comment: Sort of wondering what sort of company can't be bothered to offer a vital service like emails to its staff when it's incredibly cheap. Sending emails out using a personal email address hardly comes across as professional, not to mention the security aspects for the company.

Comment: You should not only worry about the people around, but all other means of intercepting a password -- for example, key-loggers, or a camera taping your typing of the password.

Comment: What I like to do is hit the character you're looking for, ex: "_f_" and then nonchalantly hit a bunch more fake characters, remembering the count of correct characters your password is, and then deleting until you hit the last correct one and repeating for all of them.

Comment: Why not just email the jobs to your colleagues?  They can use their personal emails if you're using yours already.

Comment: `My company does not provide company email` what sort of company does that?

Comment: Plus a million for creating a new account just for work. For my first job I used a personal account for IM. A year and a half after I quit, I was still getting messages from people thinking I still worked there :|

Comment: Learn to touch type. If you're fast enough, they won't be able to see what you type without a recording device.

Comment: Suggest to your company that they pay for office365 or gmail for domains or something. It's not just a "nice to offer to employees" thing, centrally controlling employee email is very often a *legal requirement* (or at least a really good idea in case of lawsuits/discovery/etc.), both for the company and for its employees.

Comment: Assuming you are on a Windows system that's newer than XP, you can create a batch file (**something.bat**) with `@clip < myprec.dll` and **myprec.dll** containing your password in some (and same) folder. Furthermore, you can create a link to the batch file, place it on the desktop, add a shortcut key combo to activate it anytime and make it run minimized. Yes, your password will be there in that file, but then only you will know that.. and if anyone ever finds it, they won't know what it is or what it unlocks. (101 < 10 rep for an answer!)

Comment: In my workplace, it is a common courtesy for you to turn your head upon noticing that someone is entering a password. Most of my coworkers are technically inclined, so we understand the value of others' personal security, but anyone can pick up this habit. I read this question to be more of a social issue, so I think the answer is a social fix.

Comment: @QuoraFeans I'd highlight ***cameras***. They're hard to escape. The key-loggers are hard to justify... However, cameras from 'security' to the 'smartglass' infiltrate venues previously neutral.

Comment: @LGT a small part of the password would be enough given that shoulder-surfing is rarely perfect as well.  This would mean that the PW isn't stored locally as plaintext.  Of course eacxh part of the password could be suffcientle strong on its own if you wanted.

Comment: You're not specifying whether you're using your own computer (laptop or tablet) or if you're using a company computer. Also clarifying whether you use a tablet or phone (which often shows the last typed character on secure entry fields for a second or two) would help.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't print/save the jobs list before the meeting, alleviating the need to log into your email in front of everyone? Or even just log into your email before meeting with everyone? Personally, I'd have a problem even *showing* my personal email account to a large group of people. My personal emails are personal. In any case, if you have a few minutes to do some preparation, I suggest doing so. Not having to log into your email account at all is the best option by far.

Comment: Kindly ask them to look away if you have to type in your password when a coworker is near you.

Comment: "I also cannot move the screen so my co-workers cannot see it.". With most desktop environments you can also move an active window near the bottom of the screen in such a way that the bottom of the window is no longer visible. In this condition, the text fields in the active window can still be typed blindly.

Comment: What is at risk in this scenario? Going from broad to more specific, is it learning your password itself which is the concern (*remember to use different passwords*), or is it access to your personal email, or is it access to the job lists or other specific information within the email? Each level can have different answers, as well as the answers in a more broad category - so what level of security are you comfortable with?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins [Konami](http://kotaku.com/report-konami-is-treating-its-staff-like-prisoners-1721700073), for example.

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Use the blanket of security, as seen in the Snowden documentary Citizenfour.
It involves placing a blanket over your head, the keyboard and monitor and typing in the password. 
It will look weird but for security's sake it may be worth it.

Related post with demo pic - [In CitizenFour, what was Edward Snowden mitigating with a head blanket?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82362/in-citizenfour-what-was-snowden-mitigating-with-head-blanket)

[image: A security blanket]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34438/discussion-on-answer-by-mk444-how-should-i-securely-type-a-password-in-front-of).

Comment: Worth noting that if you can touch-type your password, you don't need to put it over your head - just the keyboard.

Comment: @Bobson Depends on your threat model. In the case of what Snowden was likely worried about, I'd expect hand movement under the blanket could conceivably be monitored to sufficient accuracy to allow the number of possible passwords to at least be drastically reduced. Putting the blanket over your head and the whole keyboard with no part of it touching your hands means you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling At that point, you mine as well just turn off the lights.

Comment: @PyRulez Computer screens emit light.

Comment: @PyRulez: Snowden is probably interested in more than just the visible spectrum. Hopefully his blanket will effectively diffuse IR from his hands.

Comment: Not to mention, the vibration of the keystrokes themselves can actually give away the keys typed... using any nearby smartphone with an accelerometer... or the accelerometer in the computer itself which is there to protect the hard drive.... See http://www.cc.gatech.edu/fac/traynor/papers/traynor-ccs11.pdf

Comment: This seems like more of a "life-hack" answer - I can't imagine that this would seriously be considered "normal" for a manager to do in front of co-workers.

Comment: @Dan Skip the accelerometer. Just use the mic. Analysis of the sound could do just as well.

Comment: @DoubleDouble this question is in the context of a company who does not provide email for their workforce. I'd say any yahoo scheme will suffice. The MD still think the internet is contained in a small black box...

Comment: I wonder if this one received so many votes because of the humor value of the image. I can't imagine a manager remaining in management (or even in the company) very long using this technique. It's not very team-oriented. Saying, "Please turn away for just a second while I type my password," would be more socially acceptable in companies where I've worked.

Comment: I came here for an answer, but the comments reminds me of rick and morty thing, a universe in miniverse in nanoverse.

Answer (score 178):

You could use Two Factor Authentication that uses your phone to log in along with your password. That way, even if they see your password, they would need your phone, too to log in.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34589/discussion-on-answer-by-schroeder-how-should-i-securely-type-a-password-in-front).

Answer (score 127):

Get a password manager like [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) and store your password there. Use the [auto-type](http://keepass.info/help/base/autotype.html) or a [plugin](http://keepass.info/plugins.html) to enter the password.

- Unlock your KeePass database when you boot your machine, so that you don't have to unlock it with people around.
- Set it up so that it locks automatically when you lock the screen (just in case)

Alternatively, you can remember the e-mail password in your browser, which has downsides compared to KeePass but will keep your password save (given enough scrutiny).

Comment: I have been using keepass and it works great. it is even available in portable form so you can carry it usb. this way it will never be stored in office.

Comment: Keep in mind that passwords stored in your browser can be trivially accessed by another person using that browser (or computer, if he/she is an administrator).

Comment: Sure, but now your employer can get at your passwords. They might have to read the raw RAM of the machine and dig around to find them, but it's their machine; they can do that…

Comment: If you have an iPhone or other iOS device, you can use Safari's password keychain as a mobile, secure, not-employer-snoopable password storage device. (Settings > Safari > Passwords)

Comment: Physical access beats all defences. If I can tamper with your machine, I can just as well replace your KeePass installation with a fake that will send all the passwords to me once you decrypt the db. Bottom line: If you want to log in to your private e-mail on your employer's machine, you HAVE to trust the employer

Comment: You cannot unlock your disk encryption at boot time this way. Or simply imagine taking your laptop with you screen-locked to meet someone...

Comment: @Kos physical access attack is more costly against disk encryption. Is it not? Then, consider something like coreboot (not prioprietrary which may contain bugs or backdoors already) one day help to protect your boot path. The costs would be rised again. Isn't it just a dogma?

Comment: @Kos: I don't understand how your bullets are consistent/compatible. If the user configures KeePass to lock automatically, won't he need to unlock it when he accesses his email (when there are people around)?

Comment: @Scott agreed, the second bullet point was not that relevant, I've amended it

Comment: KeePass can use any combination of a typed password, file or Windows account as part of its unlocking mechanism.  Since OP is primarily worried about shoulder surfing, a file on a USB stick would be sufficient.  OP would never need to type in any passwords other than for their computer's login.

Answer (score 58):

While I recommend two-factor authentication on your personal account, you could set up second, work only account (as others have suggested), set up an automatic forwarding rule to it for the emails that are work related, and then log into that when necessary.

This way, you don't need to have your professional contacts update your email address, and you're only logging into an account with non-personal emails.

Answer (score 44):

> My email service is end to end encryption,

Unfortunately, when logging from an untrusted computer (your company's here) this does not mean much:

- The company may have installed the company's certificate in the trusted root of the browser you use and be proxying all the traffic through a server which essentially performs a MitM attack.
- The company may be observing the programs' memory, logging your keystrokes, ...

> which means it does not store password or reset password.

You should be able to reset your password, end-to-end encryption does not preclude resetting passwords. Select an e-mail provider/technology which allows it.

On the other hand, if you operate from an unstrusted computer, password-protecting a private key is not as effective: since the company may access any program's memory, they may access your private key after it's decoded with your password.

> I can't shift the screen.

If you are worried about your team members seeing your e-mails, then you might want to bring this point to your boss; especially if they are used to send you confidential e-mails (such as discussing the performance of some of your team members, or other personal information).

However, this should have no impact on your passwords: it should never appear on screen.

---

In light of the fact that your company may very well be "spying" on you, and possibly legally so depending on your jurisdiction:

- use a **work-only e-mail account** (do not leak your personal mails/discussions to your company)
- use a **work-only password** (do not leak your preferred password to your company)

If you wish to secure said e-mail account (to prevent others from perusing your e-mails or sending them in your behalf):

- rotate your password regularly
- use two-factor authentication, if available

Comment: preferred password is a strange thing, one should not use same password for more than one service

Comment: @SargeBorsch: That's the theory, as we all know, unfortunately, password reuse is a thing.

Comment: At the _very very least_, have one password for personal stuff, and a separate one for work stuff. And a separate one for non-reputable services likely to be hacked and throwaway accounts. And…actually, just get a password manager…

Answer (score 43):

You should assume your employer has access to your keystrokes, so even if you *do* make them look away, it won't help at all. If you still insist on this false sense of security, you should [become one with the tinfoil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDeLe.png) like Edward Snowden.

Schroeder and Neil have given two very good alternatives:

1. Create a new junk email account for work.
2. Use Two-Factor Authentication.

You could even use both `1` and `2`.

Comment: Are you saying that this is likely or that it's a possibility that can't be ignored?

Comment: Both? You can't ignore this possibility, as it may be quite likely.

Comment: "You should assume your employer has access to your keystrokes, so even if you do make them look away, it won't help at all." -- it doesn't follow that it doesn't help *at all*. Just because some colleague has physical access to install a keylogger (USB or otherwise), doesn't mean they will actually weigh up the risks and cost of making that attack, and the risks and cost of shoulder-surfing, and find them to be the same. So preventing the easiest attack actually can help a bit. You just don't know whether it will or not unless you know how motivated your colleagues are to get your password.

Comment: I'm talking about employers, and managers. In the IT industry, whether you realize it or not, managers "manage" people, and they generally have access to whatever it is that you're doing - including your keystrokes. They just don't *tell* you about it.

Comment: @MarkBuffalo: Your first sentence is a valid point, but IMHO it should be a postscript, and not a lead-in that you use to justify remarks like "false sense of security" and "tinfoil".  The question explicitly mentions "co-workers" (twice, in fact).  employer ≠ co-workers, and the OP may trust management more than he trusts his co-workers.

Comment: @Scott Yeah, but OP may be unaware that management can easily keylog him.

Comment: @MarkBuffalo: Yeah, but the question ***wasn't*** "What are all the security risks involved in using my personal account from work?"; therefore, I'm saying that your first paragraph isn't directly responsive to the question, and would have been better as a comment or a side note.

Comment: @Scott I feel you may be missing the point. I don't agree with letting someone start with a false sense of security. Part of this website is about offering different perspectives, and there may be things people haven't considered before. If the OP is worried about his password being stolen, then it follows that he should know that many employers keylog you.

Comment: @MarkBuffalo: I believe that you're missing *my* point.  The OP is worried about his password being stolen by shoulder-surfing.  We could advise him to choose a long password not based on a word, etc., etc., because that would be not only harder to guess, but also harder to shoulder-surf.  My point is that, as valuable as that advice might be, it's not an answer to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 16):

Simple. Setup your separate work email. After that setup an auto-forwarding from your personal mail to your new-work-email, for senders who don't know your new email yet and then you can be confident logging that email account in front of your colleagues.

hope it helps! :)

Comment: +1 was just about to suggest this. Create another email account that you only use for work and hence don't care if your partners see or even use it. Using your personal email as an official part of your job is a problem just waiting to happen, regardless of this particular question.

Comment: DO NOT DO THAT. If you set up forwarding, compromising your work e-mail means getting full access to all accounts linked to the personal one, using the "I forgot the password" feature.

Comment: @d33tah, you could just forward e-mails based on filters, e.g. coming from known senders or specific keywords. That way you won't forward those such ones that help you reset the password of the original account.

Answer (score 13):

A YubiKey is capable of storing a fixed string that can be activated. Make your password a combination of the a random character string that is on the YubiKey and your typed password. It's not quite two factor authentication, but it does mean shoulder surfing the keyboard alone won't be enough to get your password.

If you use GMail, they integrate with U2F and TOTP generators, in which case you can actually use proper 2 factor authentication.

Comment: This still leaves you open to a keylogger installed on the machine, though.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Physical access defeats any measure you can take. If you can't trust the machine, there's no way to authenticate yourself to the email service or trust anything.

Comment: @BlacklightShining A passive keylogger will not break U2F because it uses public key crypto.

Answer (score 9):

Buy a simple **fingerprint scanner** or use a laptop with fingerprint scanner (pretty common now a days), then use a password manager to store your password for that email service and login with a swipe of your finger.

I do that all the time with HP Client Security.

And that looks more hi-tech than *awkward* like many other solutions do in front of other people :)

Comment: A fingerprint is ***not*** a password, at best it's a user id. You leave it behind on almost everything you touch, and how can you change your "password" finger in the future? New fingers?

Comment: Probably have not used that feature ever?. Niether did i mean it is a password nor does grabbing a fingerprint from somewhere else works fine on a computer fingerprint swipe scanner in real life. You can change password anytime you want and your password manager will know the new password if you tell it.

Comment: And in an office if other people are so determined to snatch your password that they will take your fingerprints from the door knob and then generate a mold and then login to your computer then you might not as well be there in the first place looking for an answer to this question. Wouldn't such people easily take off the blanket off your head like suggested in the top answer?

Comment: The question reads *How should I securely type a password in front of a lot of people?* and not *How do I protect my password from a lot of hostile spies in my office?*

Comment: I upvoted this answer because as an I.T. guy, I frequently have people over at my desk.  It's very convenient to just swipe my finger to unlock the computer.  You don't want people to see what keys you are typing on your keyboard, but you also don't want to make them feel like you don't trust them.  The fingerprint reader is awesome.

Answer (score 8):

You could always learn to use the [Dvorak Keyboard Layout!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_Simplified_Keyboard)  You will rarely encounter anyone watching over your shoulder familiar with this layout.  I use it and I've never encountered anyone who could tell what I was typing even if I slowly pecked away with my index finger one key at a time.

Comment: But if you look at what you type and type it again, I'll use your password even if the keyboard layout is different.

Comment: this is the "lucky charms decoder ring" level of security.

Comment: Even if the don't get it by looking directly they could use a camera and decipher afterwards.

Comment: better yet, make your own. that's what I did...

Answer (score 7):

When I enter a PIN code in a grocery store, I fake a few extra key-presses between the real ones, by putting my finger on the key but not pushing it. It's especially convenient when the keys don't visibly move much (as in the case of almost all keypads I've encountered on card scanners and ATMs), but with some practice it can be done with a standard computer keyboard.

It doesn't help against people who are trained and dedicated to spy on you, or use a camera and watch it later in slow motion, but it provides a good protection against casual glances.

Comment: If you are touch typing a fake hit on a bottom row key should be basically impossible for an observer to detect unless they can also note that no * appeared in the password box when you "hit" that key.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com) and replace the full or parts of the password automatically while typing. I was using this method before I switched to [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) and used Auto-Type.

```
::pop::part0fP4$$w0rD
```

That way, users seeing you type will only know parts of the password, not the full password. Disadvantage: the second half of the password is stored in a file. To mitigate that a bit, I made the replacement longer than needed and delete a few characters using backspace.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to visually block shoulder-surfers but don't want to go full blanket-over-head-and-PC for the obvious appearance downsides, you could get a similar level of protection with less awkwardness by putting a smaller cloth over just your hands while you touch-type your password. Still awkward, but not as glaringly so. A password manager plus MFA is still generally the best choice in this scenario.

Comment: I'd appreciate if the downvoter/delete voter(s) would explain why they think this is both a bad answer and an invalid answer instead of just throwing a delete request at it.

Answer (score 3):

No blankets over your head required - just cover up a small section of the keyboard with your other hand, while typing in your password.

This would work excellent if you had all the letters on one side of the keyboard, or a numbers-only password, and have a number pad on the keyboard to type it in with. Very much like you're *supposed* to do at an ATM machine.

Like this photo too, (*only do a better job* ;-) [image]

All the caveats about your employer or company being able to monitor every keystroke and all network traffic apply, but this will keep prying eyes off at least.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, anyone in your office can just either install software on your PC, or plug in a physical keylogger between your PC and your keyboard. Of the solutions mentioned so far, only 2 factor authentication provides reasonable defense against physical access. But tampering with a computer to find somebody else's password is a criminal offence in many places and will also get people fired if caught, so the chance that they will do that is significantly lower than them just looking at your keyboard while you type.

Of the solutions mentioned so far, only 2 factor authentication provides reasonable defense against physical access.

The one solution which is missing is: BYOD. **Bring in your own laptop, tablet or phone to access your email**. That device uses an email client that has already stored your password, and the device requires a pin, fingerprint, or eye reading to unlock.

Answer (score 2):

My proposal requires support on the server.  If your service provider does provide this service (or if they are willing to), this doesn't actually answer the direct question (how to prevent the passphrase from being seen) but actually addresses the problem that most people try to solve (which is how to authenticate without revealing details that allows someone else to authenticate).  The secret is to...

Don't worry if they get your password.

There is technology called OTP (One-Time Password), such as the S/Key implementation, which allows you to type in a password onto a trusted device.  The trusted device uses some software, such as skeyinit (on Unix-like platforms -- [skyinit man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/skeyinit.1?query=skeyinit&sec=1)) or [OTPDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ub0r.android.otpdroid&hl=en) (an open source option on Android platform) to generate a series of words.  Then, *you don't need to care* if anyone thinks they saw your typed password, or even if there is a keyboard logger, because that series of words is only valid once.

If you can't type on your phone safely, another option (if you have foresight) is to generate the list of words ahead of time, and store them somewhere (maybe even using pen and paper).  Then you can look at the pre-generated note that reminds you what words will need to be typed.

Answer (score 2):

Snce you are asking..

1) shroud the keyboard. Learn to type blindly, accordion style.

2) implement opie style single use passwords.

3) login using keypairs via an ssh tunnel or similar.

4) try really hard not to mumble the password audibly as you type.

5) periodically scan for ultrasonic modem noise, unusual RF activity.

6) be acuteley aware of reflective surfaces, mirrors, glass.

7) DO NOT type it into unmasked fields accidentally.

8) Momentarily re-map your keyboard.

9) or just don't do it in public.
etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your co-workers politely to turn around for a second. In a working environment nobody should be surprised or complain.

Comment: Any work environment people should not wonder if you ask them not to spot on the keyboard while one enters credentials...

Answer (score 1):

> I am a manager in an office where the company does not provide a company email, so I use my personal email.

I agree with one of the comments: Create your own work email account in a place like gmail or on your own shared hosting web site if you have one.  It is probably more important that managers have communications distinct from their existing personal accounts.

> Often, I will receive jobs lists by email from my general manager.

Perhaps you could bring the point up to the General Manager that your work space is not conducive to the privacy of her or his emails to you, depending on the strength and candidness in that relationship.

> How should I log in to my email in front of my co-workers so that they don't see my password?

There are several options you can use with a new account.  Some of them might work in tandem.

1. You can store your password in the browser early in the morning.
2. You can make the characters not echo, depending on the mail client. (Be aware that this should definitely be in place for your operating system log-in.)
3. You can use very strong passwords and learn to type them at high speed.
4. You can say, "Please turn around," which is certainly appropriate under the circumstances.

> My email service uses end to end encryption, which means that it does not store or reset my password.

It is good that your service uses client side encryption (if that is what you mean by end to end encryption).  Perhaps that is not a necessary security measure for a company that does not have its own email server.  If it is necessary, you could encrypt the data on the computer and send the ciphertext as an attachment.

> I also cannot move the screen so my co-workers cannot see it.

It is best, in today's corporate environment, to assume that sustained privacy of display contents is not a realistic option.

I cannot speak for Windows or iOS, but with a properly configured SE LINUX system, the security level is high enough so that I can store all my passwords in such a way that I never have to type them during the workday.  Then I start work, typing the single LINUX account password (which does not echo to the display), before anyone else starts theirs.

Answer (score -2):

Get yourself a cheap barcode scanner, attach it to your computer and configure it as a "keyboard wedge" so it pretends it is a simple keyboard.

[image]

Print your password as a barcode (there are many free barcode fonts around) and stick that in a pocketbook you carry on your person.

Whenever you need to log-in, reach out your book, open it, scan the barcode and close the book.

Comment: But then, surely anyone who simply has a camera-enabled phone in your vicinity can silently snap a picture and then decode your password at their convenience?

Comment: @Thisisn'tmyrealname Yes. :) The crux is whether your staff would do this. Your call.

Comment: But doesn't the fact of the question itself imply an environment where you would have to be concerned about this?

Comment: Instead of this, I'd suggest programming a Yubikey with a static random string. The Yubikey simply emulates a keyboard. Append the string to the password you have memorized. When you need to enter your password, first type the part from memory, then insert the Yubikey into a USB slot and touch the button. It will enter the static string to complete the full password and hit enter. A key is easier to keep on your person and less obvious than scanning a barcode. Here's a tutorial: https://www.yubico.com/products/services-software/personalization-tools/static-password/

Comment: This just leaves the book as a security weakness.  This can be **partially** overcome by having multiple barcodes, you scan a few to build up your password.  The keyspace you can reasonably make this way is too small for real security but anti-flood measures should make it not work very well.