# Using AutoHotKey-like tools for usable long passwords

Tags: passwords

I recently saw [this idea](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110879/111626) of using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) to perform character replacement allowing mapping of shortcut-keys to long sequences of characters.

Consider a `.ahk` file mapping :

```
Ctrl-Alt-a --> s0k&*GHn0
Ctrl-Alt-A --> 75_+:+E@#
Ctrl-Alt-b --> <:L2389ne
... etc. ....
```

This would allow me to have freakishly long passwords for different websites but remember a much shorter sequence. e.g. with a two keystroke sequence

```
[Ctrl-Alt-a] [Ctrl-Alt-b]
```

I can type the password

```
*s0k&*GHn0<:L2389ne
```

Yes, I know -- `correct horse battery staple` may still be better, and yes, I lose portability as I know rely on having AHK and the `.ahk` file.

However, does this method buy me any increase in password security? Is it a good idea to try?

Comment: It's certainly an interesting idea.  Can you think of benefits of using this approach over a password manager?  I guess capturing the database wouldn't be enough, as you'd then have to either brute-force with your new dictionary, or keylog the entry for a site?

Comment: Isn't the script still sending the keys to be logged? In any case, some password managers have similar features, you are probably better off using one of them.

Comment: I'm completely sold on password managers. But, call it security-by-novelty, sometimes it pays to be different, as the password manager breaches start to trickle in. As for keyloggers, true, the gains are less certain-- but then again, isn't *`malware = game over`* ?

Answer (score 6):

No, It gets you a decrease in security because you now have your passwords in a searchable file.

A password manager does the same job but holds the data securely. It is also likely to have mitigation tools for common attacks.

Comment: True, but this could be mitigated by having a shortcut key replacement for all 101 * 2 (shift key) keys and you could use a different sequence of (say) 8 for each website. You're less likely to be caught n a broad attack, as no one's looking....

Comment: A reasonable point though I think that it depends on *where* an attacker is monitoring the dialog. Personally, I'd say the risks are a lot lower when using a hardened, proven, tested tool. This is one of the tenets of security - don't roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this method buy me any increase in password security? Is it a good idea to try?

Using AutoHotKey buys you a small bit of security through obscurity, because if an attacker gets access to your computer, an `.ahk` file is probably not on the list of "credential-holding files" that common exploit toolkits will look for.

Still, storing unencrypted passwords in a `.ahk` file is notably LESS secure than using an encrypted password manager.  I wouldn't consider it a good idea to use AutoHotKey for security.

Answer (score -1):

This is like using simple substitution ciphers in the computer age. You will be better off using AHK to type the hash of your password as the password.

Comment: The key substitution merely adds a layer of obfuscation on the underlying security, and this obfuscation buys longer, more complex passwords that don't have a memorization problem. I'm not sure why hashing the password helps, and how using AHK for this is more secure than my approach.

Comment: AHK = AutoHotKey (Hint: look at the file extension in your question). Hashing serves the same purpose as "obfuscation" but does it in a much more secure way: there's no way for a spear-phishing hacker to learn your dictionary from a few compromised sites.